# Python selenium chrome driver headless doesn't work

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I tried to make a bot that allows automatic purchase on the Amazon site and I did.

But Then I wanted to make the bot faster and tried to make chrome driver headless. But when I tried to
do that the bot didn't work( Actually it always going to NoSuchElement part that shouldn't go. As I said before it normally works.)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import winsound
import time


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\alpay\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User 
Data\\Default")
options.add_argument("--headless")




driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\webdrivers\\chromedriver.exe", options=options)
buyingStatus = True

while(buyingStatus):
    try:
        driver.get("Item Chrome Html")
        print(driver.title)
        beGreedy = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('quantity'))
        print(driver.title)
        beGreedy.select_by_value('1')

        addCart = driver.find_element_by_class_name("a-button-stack").submit()
        print(driver.title)
        completeTheShopping = driver.find_element_by_id("hlb-ptc-btn-native").click()
        if driver.title == "Enter The Amazon":
            driver.find_element_by_id("ap_password").send_keys("Enter Password")
            driver.find_element_by_id("signInSubmit").click()
        print(driver.title)
    

            

        buyNow =  driver.find_element_by_xpath("html")  
                                                          
        freq = 500
        dur = 2000
        winsound.Beep(freq, dur)
        print("ITEM FOUND")
        buyingStatus = False















    

        

    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("ITEM DOESN'T EXIST")
        driver.refresh()
```

So, What could be possible problem ? Could it be about that headless works too fast ?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try with user-agent

```py
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.24 Safari/537.36'

options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
```